Excecute task pane code without showing task pane at startup
I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to execute code in my task pane without rendering the task pane. I've reviewed all the relevant documentation here:


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/loading-the-dom-and-runtime-environment
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/run-code-on-document-open
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.startupbehavior?view=common-js-preview


Before launching the workbook on the web, I add the following to the workbook:
We.WebExtensionProperty webExtensionProperty1 = new We.WebExtensionProperty() { 
   Name = "Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", 
   Value = "true" };
webExtensionPropertyBag1.Append(webExtensionProperty1);

This will auto show the task pane. But in my add-in code, I do the following:
Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);

in the Office.onReady() function.
This is supposed to hide the task pane. What happens is the task pane briefly flashes and then is hidden.
What I'd like is to be able to run my task pane code, but not have the task pane flash briefly. Is this possible?
Thanks!

I think you've come as close as your going to get to what you want. The add-in runs in a full web view control on desktop (and in an iframe in Office on the web). That control has to start up to load anything, including code. There is a JavaScript-only runtime in some add-ins, but it is for special uses, like custom functions in Excel.

Thanks Rick. We are online only right now and your explanation makes perfect sense. I figured that there has to be some part of the task pane being loaded for the code to be able to execute. I might try and have a blank visual appearance for the task pane in this phase so that the visual flash isn't that bad.
